# Android Broadcast Receiver Not triggering

Tags: android

Figured out the issue in my code - answer at bottom of post.

I am learning how to work with broadcast receivers in android.
I have create a receiver class and registered it in the manifest.

When I run my app it does not trigger.

I think it is because the receiver has to be called at least once manually before it will be able to be triggered automatically by the android OS.
although as I am new to this, I could be mistaken.

I am learning from the [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/) and [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/android.html) sites.

I need to know how to get it to actually trigger when I receive an incoming call.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<receiver android:name="PhoneCallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My Broadcast class is as follows and resides in the java folder

```
package com.teqnet.receivers;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;  


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Receiver Triggered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    }
    else{
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            Toast.makeText(context,"Phone Ringing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}

//Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

//Deals with actual events

//Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
//Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if(lastState == state){
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            Toast.makeText(context,savedNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
               // onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
              //  onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            else if(isIncoming){
               // onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            else{
              //  onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

}

and lastly my main activity file. Note I am not doing anything there as I am just trying to trigger toast messages to confirm receiver is being triggered

```
package com.teqnet.receivers;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

In your manifest file make sure that your receiver is listed within the application tags.
I am posting the corrected manifest file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="PhoneCallReceiver" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
       </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Simple mistake but it cost me a days work ;).
Good Luck Everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, Go to Apps., Select the app that is currently the default launcher for a certain file type. Try selecting your app manually here. If it works, then you need to ask for set default permissions to user on the first launch.

Otherwise try this;

```
import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);                     
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());                       
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());                                               
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

Add the following to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>

<!--This part is inside the application-->
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Usage example:

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
    }

}
```

For more: [Tutorial & Source](http://gabesechansoftware.com/is-the-phone-ringing/#more-8)

Comment: On my android phone?

Comment: My phone does not allow me to change any settings for the app. I can force stop or uninstall that is all ;(. Testing through my phone.

Comment: Try this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager&hl=en

Comment: That's where I got this sample from, but i don't want to implement it in a class by extending the broadcastreceiver. I want to call a service on phone ringing. that is why I am just trying to get it to trigger the receiver so I can check if it works ;)

Comment: redid it exactly like the tutorial, also added enabled = true in manifest for this receiver. no joy

Comment: tried the same application on android studio emulator, with no joy.

Comment: thank you for all your help zahid. really appreciated